# How do I know what my next Atlas task is?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I am trying to follow the Atlas path. I keep seeing the little objectives in the lower right of my screen but I have no idea how to get them to show up manually. Is there some place I can check or a button that will make them show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing left on the D-Pad or <kbd>h</kbd> should display it. Otherwise, I have yet to find another way.

Comment: It also seems to pop up automatically once every few minutes for me.

Comment: I get the once in a while pop-up as well. But it's never when I need it :P